# How to make a crowd of people running using one person in VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, effects

Lets suppose I animate a scene 20 or 30 times from the same angle, but with character(s) running in different directions? Such as escaping a doomed city.

Ideally there would be some 20 or 30 takes (one for each person running) from camera angle, and I'd like to impose them on top of each-other so it appears to be a mass exodus from a town.

How is this done in VSE? Is it too much on Blender to do it?

Comment: "*Is it too much on Blender to do it?*" It probably is, for the VSE at least it sounds like an inadequate tool. Maybe the compositor might be able to

Comment: wouldn't that be a _mass exodus_ of cloned people...?

Comment: If you use filmed people from a locked off camera, the issue will be masking or keying the individuals into the background plate/image. Ideally you would difference key them from their background (where pixels change color from a sample you get a key shape). But this rarely works. Otherwise shoot greenscreen. Also you need to avoid shooting a shared floor as the people may occupy the same position. Much easier to film a low point of view and compress the people in frame.

Comment: The VSE doesn't allow you to do keying very easily, see this tutorial I made: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1mVm4hwO0EU  but the compositor does. The drawback there is that changing the start frame per person will be a bit of a pain and not very interactive. You don't just slide a strip like in the VSE.